# Running Iperf Server and Client using Multithreading in Python causes Segmentation fault

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, iperf3

A main class calls two other classes(IperfServer and IperfClient) and I'm trying to run them using multithreading. I am using the python wrapper class for iperf3. Both the classes are initiated but while running Iperf, I get segmentation Fault.

CODE SNIPPET:

```
class IperfServer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print("1")
        server = iperf3.Server()
        print("2")
        server.port = 5201
        response = server.run()

class IperfClient(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print("3")
        connection = http.client.HTTPSConnection("abc.efg")
        print("4")
        connection.request(method="GET", url="/hij/")
        response = connectn.getresponse()
        connectn.close()

        print("5")
        client = iperf3.Client()
        client.run()

class IperfAgent(object):
    thread1 = IperfClient()
    thread2 = IperfServer()

    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
```

OUTPUT:

3

1

Segmentation Fault

I'm a newbie to python and multithreading. Could someone help me figure out the mistake I am making?

Comment: For the client, shouldn't you use the `iperf3.client()`?

Comment: Yeah. I've used that below the `print("5")` statement.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @h3ct0r, Yes, as William Qian suggested, I ran them as subprocess and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running it in a subprocess (see multiprocessing.Process) instead of a thread.

It appears that iperf_defaults requires being run on a main thread.